# jSlider jQuery plugin: Set a minimum range, and format minimum value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

I am using [jSlider](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/) to implement a touch-friendly range slider, but I have two problems:

1. I would like to set a minimum **range** of $10, but I don't seem to be able to do this. (In other words, there's always at least $10 between the lower and upper values.)
2. I can't get the minimum **value** to format correctly as $0 - it's showing `$` rather than `$0` (actually I'd prefer it to be `$1` but I can't implement that either).

I've set up a JSFiddle with my slider: http://jsfiddle.net/v3gUg/9/

Here is the code too, for reference:

```
var options = { 
  from: 0,
  to: 500,
  round: 10, 
  heterogeneity: ['50/100', '75/250'], 
  scale: ["£0", '|', "£50", '|' , "£100", '|', "£250", '|', "£500"],
  limits: true,
  step: 10,
  format: { format: '£#' }, // Doesn't return 0 correctly. 
  skin: "round_plastic",
  onstatechange: function() { 
      // Check range here and return false if too small?
      // But return false doesn't seem to do anything. 
     return false;
  }
};
jQuery("#price-slider").slider(options);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to either problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
       $(document).ready(function() { 

  var options = { 
      from: 0,
      to: 500,
      round: 10, 
      heterogeneity: ['50/100', '75/250'], 
      scale: ["$0", '|', "$50", '|' , "$100", '|', "$250", '|', "$500"],
      limits: true,
      step: 10,
      format: { format: '$#,' },
      skin: "round_plastic",
    callback: function() { 
      // if (range too small)
      //return false;
    },
  onstatechange: function( value ){
    var array = value.split(";");

    if(array[0] == array[1])
    {
      value = array[0]+";"+array[1];
      $(".holder").slider("value", p1, p2)
    }
  } 
    };
  jQuery("#price-slider").slider(options);

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I want the minimum *range* to be $10, not the minimum value. I want the minimum value to be $0 or $1. I'll edit the question so it's clearer.

Comment: Ok, the value problem is solved: format: { format: '$#,' }(i've added a comma after the #).
But i don't understand what you mean whit range, my englisch is not so good

Comment: Thanks! By "range" I mean, let the lower value of the slider not be less than $10 below (or equal to) the upper value. So $280-$290 is an acceptable range, but $290-$290 isn't.

Comment: See my new edit, i got something but i don't realy know what to fill in p1 and p2($(".holder").slider("value", p1, p2)). I tryed every thing but without succes, maybe you can get it work from here?

Comment: This is a great try, but for me, calling `.slider` again creates a brand new slider. I'll raise a GitHub ticket for a minimum range. I'll accept the answer anyway, since you solved the minimum value question. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @apero I just replaced p1 and p2 with 5 and 7. `$(".holder").slider("value", p1, p2)` -> `$(".holder").slider("value", 5, 7)`.
p1 and p2/5 and 7 denote the values that the left and right pointers are at.